# Determine when the given proposition is true

Tags: logic

The question asks to determine **when** the following proposition is true using truth-tables:

[image]

When I construct a truth-table, I have the following:

[image]

Thus for the whole proposition:
[image]

So, am I correct in saying that this proposition is **never** true?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: As you can see, you can stop the checking to the first part: a *conjunction* is TRUE when both conjuncts are. Thus, being the first conjunct always FALSE, the complete conjunction can never be TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct. You could simplify the check by using some “propositional identities”: for instance, you can prove that
$$
A\land(B\lor C)\equiv (A\land B)\lor(A\land C)
$$
so in your case you can substitute $\lnot Q\land(\lnot P\lor Q)$ with
$$
(\lnot Q\land\lnot P)\lor(\lnot Q\land Q)
$$
Since $\lnot Q\land Q$ is always false, you can substitute the whole with $\lnot Q\land \lnot P$. Thus the first block becomes (equivalent to)
$$
P\land(\lnot Q\land\lnot P)
$$
Oh, well, this is false for every $P$ and $Q$, because of
$$
X\land Y\equiv Y\land X
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
A\land(B\land C)\equiv (A\land B)\land C
$$
so
$$
P\land(\lnot Q\land\lnot P)\equiv
P\land(\lnot P\land\lnot Q)\equiv
(P\land\lnot P)\land\lnot Q
$$